# Most appropriate test for A/B testing results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value, z-test

I looked answers for this question but couldn't find anything clear, everyone says something different.

I wonder what is the most appropriate method for testing the statistical significance of our A/B testing results. Currently, we are using Chi-Sqr but I am not sure if it is good or not for us.

For example:

```
version A: 90,000 visitors, 50,000 purchases
version B: 45,000 visitors, 25,700 purchases
```

I want to test if there is a significant difference between the conversion rates of two versions.

Comment: More information is needed. Is the design pre-post? Is the response categorical? Are there 0 cell counts or otherwise small sample sizes? If the answers are No/Yes/No, then a (Pearson) "Chi-Square test" (of independence) is reasonable.

Comment: @AdamO I added an example to first post

Comment: Are you interesting in purchases (50000 vs 25700) or rate of purchases (50/90 vs 25.7/45)$? Generally, we are interesting on rate, but in your situation maybe you just focus on purchase.

Comment: I focus on rates

Comment: What is called "conversion rate"?

Comment: https://www.wordstream.com/conversion-rate

Comment: Side note -  Even if version B yields a statistically significantly larger ratio,  the difference is only ~1.5%. So I recommend checking whether the 1.5% increment is also significant in your business.  Also, the purchase ratio is surprisingly high! How can you make half of the visitors do a purchase? If it is only an example and the actual purchases rate is very close to zero, then the Normal approximation would be not valid.

Comment: @JaeHyeokShin These are hypothetical numbers, actual conversion rate(purchase ratio for this example) is much lower, but we don't always test for purchases. There are such goals as button clicks, session duration etc. Assuming rates are close to zero, 1-2%, how would it make approximation invalid?

Comment: @E.Dogan Chi-squared test is based on Normal approximation of binomial distribution which is good when np is large. For small np, Poisson approximation is more accurate so it is better to use a test based on Poisson distributions. For details about poisson approximation, you can check e.g., http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/241.fall2014/notes2014/Poisson.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Here is a test of two proportions in Minitab. It uses a normal approximation
which should be accurate for such large numbers of counts. Because
the square of a standard normal distribution is chi-squared with one degree of
freedom, a chi-squared test on a $2 \times 2$ table would be essentially
the same. There are minor differences in how (or whether) various programs
implement 'continuity correction'.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample      X      N  Sample p
1       50000  90000  0.555556
2       25700  45000  0.571111

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0155556
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0211635, -0.00994764)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
    Z = -5.44  P-Value = 0.000
```

The P-value is so small that it is hard to imagine a valid test
would not find a significant difference between A and B proportions.
[Minitab shows P-values to three places, so output `0.000` indicates
a P-value below $0.0005.]$

It would have been easier to know what is puzzling you if you had
shows differences from various tests. Your data seem to be severely
rounded; you should use actual counts in such an analysis.

*Note:* If all four counts were divided by 100, then *proportions* would
be the same, but they would not be significantly different. Sample size matters.

```
Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       500  900  0.555556
2       257  450  0.571111
...
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
    Z = -0.54  P-Value = 0.587
```

Comment: Instead of including the total numbers of visitors in the table, I used conversions and non-conversions(total_visits - conversion), since the visitors are directed the different versions by software and not equally distributed always. What I did was to calculate the expected conversions for each version ((total_conversions / total_visitors) * total_visits_on_version_x), then compared two 2x2 matrixes with an excel function (CHITEST). We have very close p-values though. I am not an expert on statistics, excuse my mistakes.

Comment: Results should be OK if total visitor counts and conversion rates are both accurate. But if the claimed numbers of total visitors were due to bragging rather than counting, you could be in trouble. // Have to be careful these days: politicians claim 'millions and millions' when they actually talked to half a dozen supporters.

Comment: No aggregated claims, no assumptions, no nothing :) They are precise numbers of visitors of a webpage. Thank you for your help.